# phpexcel codeigniter Validation check if cells in one row empty or not

Tags: php, codeigniter, phpexcel, codeigniter-3

I have 'import from excel' function in my codeigniter 3 using phpexcel, but i want to create a validation system to check if some cells are empty or not and can detect which column and row is that before the data can be imported into my database. And if detected, import function should stop.

here's the controller :

```
public function do_upload(){


    $config['upload_path'] = './tempDat/';
    $config['allowed_types'] = 'xlsx|xls';

    $this->load->library('upload', $config);

    if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload()){
        $error = array('error' => $this->upload->display_errors());
    }
    else{
        $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());
        $upload_data = $this->upload->data(); 
        $filename = $upload_data['file_name'];
        $this->client->upload_data($filename);
      //  unlink('./tempDat/'.$filename);
        redirect('client/upload','refresh');
    }
}
```

here's the model i already tried :

```
public function upload_data($filename){
    ini_set('memory_limit', '-1');
    $inputFileName = './tempDat/'.$filename;
    try {
    $objPHPExcel = PHPExcel_IOFactory::load($inputFileName);
    } catch(Exception $e) {
    die('Error loading file :' . $e->getMessage());
    }

    $worksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->toArray(null,true,true,true);

    $numRows = count($worksheet);

    $objWorksheet = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet();
    $highestRow = $objWorksheet->getHighestRow(); 
    $highestColumn = $objWorksheet->getHighestColumn(); 


    for ($i=2; $i < ($numRows+1) ; $i++) { 

       $test = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:A'.$i);
 if( $test != NULL ) {  

        $ins = array(
                "eng_code"          => $worksheet[$i]["B"],
                "name_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["C"],
                "name_2"          => $worksheet[$i]["D"],
                "divisi"          => $worksheet[$i]["E"],
                "title"          => $worksheet[$i]["F"],
                "sex"                       => $worksheet[$i]["G"],
                "date_of_birth"          => $worksheet[$i]["H"],
                "date_of_commencement"          => $worksheet[$i]["I"],
                "salary_min_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["J"],
                "allowance_min_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["K"],
                "salary"          => $worksheet[$i]["L"],
                "allowance"          => $worksheet[$i]["M"],
                "termination_date"          => $worksheet[$i]["N"],
                "type_of_termination"          => $worksheet[$i]["O"],
                "manfaat_termination"          => $worksheet[$i]["P"],
                "basic_salary_at"          => $worksheet[$i]["Q"],
                "basic_allowance_at"          => $worksheet[$i]["R"],
                "status_employee_min_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["S"],
                "status_employee"          => $worksheet[$i]["T"],


               );


         $this->db->insert('tb_eec', $ins);
    } else {

        if( $test == NULL || $test == '') {

         $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div style="color:blue;"><b>Kolom '.$worksheet[1]["A"].' Baris '.$i.' Belum diisi !</b></div>');

         }
    }
    }
}
```

i tried many different way but the result is always the same, my function always continue to import the data even though some cells are empty.

help me please :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Am I right in thinking this is what you are after?

```
$inserts = array();

for ($i=2; $i < ($numRows+1) ; $i++) { 

    $test = $objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->rangeToArray('A1:A'.$i);

    $do_insert = true;

    foreach (range('B','T') as $let){
        if (empty($worksheet[$i][$let])){
            $do_insert = false;
        }
    }

    if ($do_insert){
        $inserts[] = array(
            "eng_code"          => $worksheet[$i]["B"],
            "name_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["C"],
            "name_2"          => $worksheet[$i]["D"],
            "divisi"          => $worksheet[$i]["E"],
            "title"          => $worksheet[$i]["F"],
            "sex"                       => $worksheet[$i]["G"],
            "date_of_birth"          => $worksheet[$i]["H"],
            "date_of_commencement"          => $worksheet[$i]["I"],
            "salary_min_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["J"],
            "allowance_min_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["K"],
            "salary"          => $worksheet[$i]["L"],
            "allowance"          => $worksheet[$i]["M"],
            "termination_date"          => $worksheet[$i]["N"],
            "type_of_termination"          => $worksheet[$i]["O"],
            "manfaat_termination"          => $worksheet[$i]["P"],
            "basic_salary_at"          => $worksheet[$i]["Q"],
            "basic_allowance_at"          => $worksheet[$i]["R"],
            "status_employee_min_1"          => $worksheet[$i]["S"],
            "status_employee"          => $worksheet[$i]["T"],
        );
    }
}

if (count($inserts)){
    foreach ($inserts as $ins){
        $this->db->insert('tb_eec', $ins);
    }
} else {
    $this->session->set_flashdata('pesan', '<div style="color:blue;"><b>Kolom '.$worksheet[1]["A"].' Baris '.$i.' Belum diisi !</b></div>');
}
```

Comment: thanks for the response, but unfortunately is not work like what i'm after.. if i have 5 row data, it's only insert one data to database even though every cell is not empty

Comment: and if column A3 have empty cell, it stil insert the first row to database. what i want is if the system detech any empty cell then no data will insert to database..

Comment: i'm sorry, the result still the same. if every cell is complete it's only insert the first row, and if the second row have empty cell the system still insert the first row. it works only if one column is all empty i.e (B1:B5).

any idea? :(

Comment: ah i see, to stop all the process if system found empty cells just add redirect when checking $do_insert false or not. thanks @Antony

Comment: Glad you got there :o)